# Wrong NavigationType on chrome android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

On chrome android, **NavigationType** is "*navigate*" instead of "*back_forward*" when i press the back button to go to the previous page.

Is it a bug ? This code works well on PC, but not on mobile :

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
    
    var navType = String(window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type);
    
     if(navType == "back_forward"){//performance.navigation.type == 2){
         
            //do something
        }
});
```